# How to make a scroll div height only as big as sibling div in row

Tags: html, css

Is this possible with just css? There are two siblings elements. The 2nd element has height that is only big enough to fit its children (children may change over time). The 1st element should have the same height as the 2nd element. If its content is larger than its height then it should overflow with scroll.

The snippet below does not match this because the 1st element takes up as much height as it needs to fully display its contents.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#container {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #000;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  width: fit-content;
}

#first {
  background-color: #00F;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 100%;
}

#second {
  background-color: #0F0;
  height: fit-content;
  width: 200px;
}

#block {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: #F00;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="first">
    <div id="block">
    </div>
    <div id="block">
    </div>
    <div id="block">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="second">
    <div id="block">
    </div>
    <div id="block">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should wrap the `#first` with extra wrapper and apply the background color to it. And use `height:0 min-height:100%` trick on the `#first`

I also fixed your html mistake. An ID can only be used once per page. So I changed the `#block` as `.block`

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#container {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #000;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  width: fit-content;
}

.scroll-area {
  overflow-y:auto;
  background-color: #00F;
}

#first {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 0;
}

#second {
  background-color: #0F0;
  /* height: fit-content; // unnecessary */
  width: 200px;
}

.block {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: #F00;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="scroll-area">
    <div id="first">
      <div class="block">
      </div>
      <div class="block">
      </div>
      <div class="block">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="second">
    <div class="block">
    </div>
    <div class="block">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```